# Bootcamp - Function key `fn` of my MBP not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, boot-camp, windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 on my 2014 MBP. All seems fine but the only problem up to now seems to be that the key `fn` is not working and therefore I cannot trigger the extra functionalities attached to all those function keys (f1, f2 etc.) And also I cannot delete a file via keyboard because the keybinding `fn + delete` cannot be triggered. Did anybody else have this problem and is there any solution?

Comment: ask the apple support for a win10 compatible bootcamp version.

Answer (score 3):

The driver for Windows 8.1 works with 10, so you just need to grab that.

Go to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048 and find your machine in the list. You want to look for the zip file download of the Boot Camp Assistant software (the link will be the number *5*).

Download that file (it's pretty big - 882Mb for my one) and unzip that once done.

Inside the unpacked folder, go into the *BootCamp* folder and then into the *Drivers* folder under that.

Go into the Apple folder and you'll find *AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe*. Run this installer and you get updated drivers and a working *fn* key.

Comment: There's seems to be no download link for models later than 2014. They ask to directly download the software from Bootcamp, however that requires an external USB disk. Maybe there's a way around it?

Comment: Just grab the most recent one. I've got the early 2015 model and it worked fine.

Comment: More direct link please? There are a lot of options here.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved by going to the Boot Camp control panel from my Windows Install, then going to the Keyboard tab and Checking the Use all F1, F2, etc standard function keys. Worked like a charm.